# admob live ads not showing on ios but android ads show (prod)

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-admob

I have a ionic app. I want to implement cordova-admob-free plugin. It's been more than a month since i've created the ad units. Ads work perfectly in test on both android and ios. When i publish to store, android works fine and show ads but ios ads not showing. There is a white area instead of banner ads.You can see the banner ad in the photo below. It is not fully understood from the photograph, but an advertisement should have appeared in that white space. Interstitial and reward ads are not displayed at all. **Also in my admob account there are lots of requests for ios, but the view is 0**

[image]

I tired following methods:

1- I added a payment method on my admob account.

2- It's been 1 week since I published my app.So I think I've waited enough.

3- I'm sure the ads ids and unit ads are correct.

4- I pasted the following code in the config file to the ios platform

```
<config-file parent="GADApplicationIdentifier" target="*-Info.plist">
        <string>ca-app-pub-6807563077792237~85445xxxxx</string>
    </config-file>
    <config-file parent="GADIsAdManagerApp" target="*-Info.plist">
        <true />
    </config-file>
```

This is my config.xml admob settings:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-admob-free" spec="~0.27.0">
    <variable name="ADMOB_APP_ID" value="ca-app-pub-6807563077792237~126763xxxx" />
</plugin>
<plugin name="cordova-admob-sdk" spec="^0.24.1" />
```

my banner settings:

```
bannerConfig: AdMobFreeBannerConfig = {
    id: this.globalSettings.isAndroid() ? 'xx' : 'yy’,
    autoShow: true
}

showBannerAd() {
    if (this.globalSettings.isRunningOnDevice()) {
      this.adMob.banner.config(this.bannerConfig);
      this.adMob.banner.prepare().then(() => {
      }).catch(e => console.log(e));
    }
  }
```

plugin list:

```
cc.fovea.cordova.purchase 10.1.1 "Purchase"
cordova-admob-sdk 0.24.1 "AdMob SDK"
cordova-admobsdk 7.49.0 "Google Mobile Ads SDK for Cordova"
cordova-clipboard 1.3.0 "Clipboard"
cordova-plugin-admob-free 0.27.0 "Cordova AdMob Plugin"
cordova-plugin-app-version 0.1.12 "AppVersion"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.3 "Device"
cordova-plugin-extension 1.5.4 "Cordova Plugin Extension"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 6.0.0 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 3.0.0-dev "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.4 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-wkwebviewxhrfix 0.1.0 "WKWebView XHR Fix"
cordova-promise-polyfill 0.0.2 "cordova-promise-polyfill"
cordova-sqlite-storage 5.1.0 "Cordova sqlite storage plugin - cordova-sqlite-storage plugin version"
```

Ionic info:

```
Ionic:



Ionic CLI          : 5.4.16 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.9
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.3

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 7.0.0, ios 6.1.1
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0, (and 10 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res (update available: 0.15.2) : 0.8.1
   native-run                             : not installed

System:

   ios-deploy : 1.10.0
   ios-sim    : 8.0.2
   NodeJS     : v12.13.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm        : 6.12.0
   OS         : macOS Big Sur
   Xcode      : Xcode 12.3 Build version 12C33
```

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: hi, I don't know if it is a coincidence, but after waiting 10 days, I found and selected my application from the admob-application settings-application store section. After a few hours, the ads started showing up.

Comment: Apparently it can take a few weeks for admob to link an IOS app. We just need to be more patient. But it's very frustrating. One wonders why it takes so long...

Answer (score 0):

You need to link your ios app with Admob in Admob App settings.